# Maximize RAM for PHP/MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have some php scripts that are parsing huge amounts of data from csv files (100gb+) into MYSQL tables. I want to allocate every possible amount of memory to this task.

Does this line of code allow me to increase the memory allocated to the script and if so what is the max amount of RAM I can set it to?

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2G');
```

My PC has:
Windows 8
16gb RAM

Comment: May be you need to chunk data and make some cron jobs with your app. Btw your question is unclear.

Comment: The 100gb is not true imho

Comment: How do you expect to keep 100G of data in 2G of memory?

Comment: Does the ini_set('memory_limit', '2G') mean I can only parse 2GB of data?  If not, how much can I parse at most?  Ive heard with Windows 8 I have more resources.  I am hoping for something constructive rather than sarcastic comments.  Thank you.

Comment: @ArjunSingh oh well, you can do it with 2 gb ram via chunking data for eg 100 mb. It spends a lot of time and `time == money` (primarily opinion based.) As @pguardiario said; how do you keep a huge data with a small memory? I also dont recommend inserting a big data to mysql via php. Find a better way.

Answer (score 1):

No, shorthand notation works only in php.ini ( http://php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes ). Use integer value in bytes instead.

Answer (score 0):

yes this line of code should work, but why do you make this in php for 100gb+ :O ?